# Websocket disconnecting if data in DB cross 3k for limit 20 only

Tags: graphql

I am facing issue with GRAPH-QL
I am using VUE-APPLO and using my own server for hasura setup.
My issue is web-socket is disconnecting  several time if we have more then 3k data in our DB, on less data it is working fine and fast.
even we are fetching data with limit 20, then also it takes 1 min to get response "if we have data more then 3k" and between this graphql web-socket disconnect reconnect several time.